# Why can't I overwrite an array (which passed to another function)with a dynamically allocated array?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

Here is the code I tried:

```
    void check(char*, int);
int main(){
    int len;
    char* str="stack over flow";
    len=strlen(str);
    check(str,len);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
void check(char* str,int len)
{
    char* arr;int i=0;
    arr=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*len);
    arr="over flow stack";
    while(arr[i]!='')
    {
        str[i]=arr[i];//here the error is thrown
        i++;
    }
    puts(str);
}
```

when I tried to print back elements of arr into str I'm getting error.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: Hint: `str[i]` is not modifiable. It point to a string literal.

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 0):

You're first allocating memory with malloc, then you're changing that pointer to point to `"over flow stack"`, then you're trying to copy characters from `"over flow stack"` over the constant string `"stack over flow"`, which has undefined behaviour, thus your program crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Using a literal string doesn't allocate any memory - it's being put into the read only space of your program.  You can't update this piece of memory.

To get memory you can overwrite you could do something like char* str = strdup("stack over flow");

You're still going to run into issues if the arr in the check function is longer than str